# Intel virtualization technology : how to load guest general purpose register?

Tags: kernel, virtualization, hypervisor

In intel software developper manual, they talk about how to load some guest states such as control register, debug register, RIP, RFLAGS, etc. but nothing about anywhere in the VMCS we could load general purpose registers from.
And google does not help more than that.
Any idea?

Comment: IIRC you need to save general purpose registers to stack (or another location) on the beginning of your VM exit handler. Look at for inspiration SImpleVisor – https://github.com/ionescu007/SimpleVisor.

Comment: @MartinDrab, thank you